# Convert UTC to desired time zone

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am working on SQL Server 2016+ and trying to convert UTC datetime to target datetime. My UTC datetimes are without offset information; how can I convert it to target time zone?

I am using `AT TIME ZONE` syntax, but since I have datetime without offset, it converts it into datetimeoffset. I also tried putting `AT TIME ZONE` syntax in inner query, like first convert datetime to datetime with offset & then convert that in outer query to target time zone, using `AT TIME ZONE` 2 times like below:

```
SELECT 
    DataTimeStamp AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time' [LocalTime],
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         DateAdd(Minute, DateDiff(Minute, 0, i.DataTimeStamp) / 60 * 60, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time' as 'DataTimeStamp' .....) t
```

Output is 2020-01-15 07:00:00.000 -07:00, what I expect is 2020-01-15 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

First define the timezone of the datetime values as utc (AT utc) and then calculate to your local timezone with a subsequent (AT timezone). The result is datetimeoffset, since you want local datetime, cast the datetimeoffset to datetime

```
select 
cast('20200118 10:00:00' as datetime)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time', ----utc as base timezone of datetime value then from utc to mountain st , datetimeoffset
cast(cast('20200118 10:00:00' as datetime)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time' as datetime) --datetime at local::mountain st timezone
```